# use an IIF atatement in a form of access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I have created a Form with the fiedls of the table and i am calculating the GrossPay and Total Deductions in the Form based on the No of Working Days.
So,Every thing is working fine when an employee has Working Days.Now my question is if an employee doesnot work for the whole month then the grossPay and Total Deductions should be Zero.But in my Form when enter working Days =0 its displaying value in the GrossPay and TotalDeductions because of the fixed HRA and Transport amount .Where as it should display 0 if Working Days is 0.

I am using the following calculation in my 
GrossPay=[EarnedSalary+EarnedAllowance+HRA+Transport].
Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do that actually - if you work things out on a daily basis and then multiply by number of days worked, if it is zero, the result will also be zero. But in answer to the question in the title, you'd want something like `IIF([WorkingDays]=0,[GrossPay]=0,[GrossPay]=[EarnedSalary]+[EarnedAllowance]+[HRA]+[Transport]`.

Comment: I want to run this on Monthly basis and when i give WorkingDays as 0 then EarnedSalary and EarnedAllowance is ok Its populating to 0.
I want to populate GrossSalary also as 0. In the Form i have a Calculated Field for GrossPay Now if i want to Write the IIF statement in which event i can write it.